# Makefile with rules compiling with different flags

Tags: makefile

I'm currently trying to write a Makefile that allows for compilation using debug symbols and without depending on the rule used, while only using a single variable. The "regular" compilation should not have debug symbols, but the "debug" one should. This is what I have currently, but this makes it always use debug symbols (I think the `eval` statement is evaluated when reading the makefile maybe?)

I also have to keep this number of variables, and prevent make from running itself (for example simply running make inside of debug using an override).

Is there a way to edit a variable inside of a rule that only applies to that specific rule?

```
# variable declaration

CFLAGS = -Wall -Wextra -Werror
CC ?= gcc
SRC = file1.c file2.c main.c file3.c
OBJ = $(SRC:.c=.o)
EXEC = programm

# Main compiler rule, compiles all obj into final executable.
$(EXEC): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJ)

# Runs the regular compiling method with additional debug information (flag "-g")
debug : $(eval CFLAGS += -g) $(EXEC);

# Compiles different files into their .o counterparts
%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

# removes building .o files
clean:
        find . -name '*.o' -delete

# runs clean and remove programm
fclean: clean
        rm -rf $(EXEC)

# runs fclean and rebuilds programm
re : fclean $(EXEC)

# runs fclean and rebuilds programm with debug information
redebug : fclean debug
```

Comment: Isn't this what Target-Specific Variables do, exactly?  https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html  You're right that you can't use `eval` here to do what you want, and you're right about the reason.

Comment: The debug flag must be applied in the *compiling* step (building `file1.o`), not in the *linking* step (combining `file1.o`, `file2.o`... to create `program`. So there can be two different versions of `file1.o`, one with debugging symbols and one without. Do want to give them different names? Put them in different directories? Run `fclean` before every build? You must decide what you want Make to do, before you write the makefile.

Comment: I had forgotten about this question and ended up making something disguisting... But MadScientist brought the answer, the target-specific variables are exactly what I needed. Thanks ! (if you want to post it again a an answer, I will gladly mark it at the solution ^^)